# TypeScript - Wait till array.sort finishes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to display a loading screen until an array is sorted in Angular. I have used the following code to do so.

```
this.isSorting = true;
this.array = this.array.sort((a,b) => a.totlaTime - b.totalTime);
this.isSorting = false;
```

But as soon as `isSorting` is made true, it becomes false. I believe it's because the `.sort` function is asynchronous. How can I wait unit the sorting and array is populated to make `isSorting = false`?

Comment: "I believe its because the `sort` function is" ...  just doing the job fast. `sort` function is not asynchronous. If you want you can add `await` before the sort as this `this.array = await this.array.sort(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Array#sort is guaranteed to be synchronous by the JavaScript specification

Note that the sort used is implementation defined (and actually varies across implementation), it is also not guaranteed to be stable.

Js sorting algorithm is quite fast to finish with processing entries. Try to write the code without setting issorting to false so you can see whether it is correct or not. In order to see the result, to have sence how it will behave when you want to sort a longer list which might take some time modify the code this way

```
this.isSorting = true;
this.array = this.array.sort((a,b) => a.totlaTime - b.totalTime);
// This section will wait for 3 sec before settings sorting to false
setTimeout(()=>{ 
  this.isSorting = false;
 }, 3000);
```

Comment: [EXMAScript 2021 specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort) says it *must* be stable (although I've not tried to check all previous specification versions)

Comment: Woops. Didnt read about this one yet. Thx for the info

Comment: @crashmstr that's a recent addition to the spec (2019 i believe).

Comment: @SándorJankovics the timeout function will wait always 3 seconds, no matter the sort is finish or not. The solution I want is to make the isSort = false, at the moment the sorting is done. Can't we achieve that?

Comment: Please read my answear again. This was just an example to see whether it works or not. My idea is that it finishes so fast you just dont see the progress bar

Comment: during the times like when the array contain elements around 10000, the isSorting becomes false fast, but the result takes way longer to appear. Thus, the loading screen disappear even before the array is finished sorting.